# How to blend two colors a specific amount

Tags: algorithm, colors, blending

so how would you blend two colors?

Like you input **color1**, **color2** and **amount**, so if **amount** is 0, it's **100% color1** and if **amount** is 1 it's **100% color2**. Anything between is a mix of both.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#Programming_language_support).

```
new_color_r = color1_r * (1 - amount) + color2_r * amount
new_color_g = color1_g * (1 - amount) + color2_g * amount
new_color_b = color1_b * (1 - amount) + color2_b * amount
```

Comment: If you do linear interpolation in RGB, then mixes of vibrant colors will go grayish in the middle.  If you want to avoid that, you can convert to HSV, interpolate in that space, and convert back.  If the colors are complimentary that can get a bit weird, so maybe a combination of the two depending on how differently hued they are.